How to filter a SwiftData query with multiple conditions?
static func GetCardsToLearnPredicate() -> Predicate<Card> {     
    let todayMinus3Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -3)
    let todayMinus7Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -7)
    let todayMinus14Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -14)
    let todayMinus30Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -30)
        
    return #Predicate<Card> {card in
        card.box == 1 || (card.box == 2 && card.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus3Days) || (card.box == 3 && card.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus7Days) || (card.box == 4 && card.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus14Days) || (card.box == 5 && card.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus30Days)
    }
}

I get the error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.
That is where the predicate is used:
@Query(filter: Card.GetCardsToLearnPredicate())
var fetchedCards: [Card]

If I try to breaking it up into sub-expressions with some lets, then the compiler tells me that a Predicate is only allowed to have one line of expression.
I already excluded the date manipulation because the compiler don't get it inside the predicate.
I don't know what to do, also Google doesn't help me out. It can't be the truth that I can't query data with only 1 or 2 expressions.
I'm new in the iOS Swift field, was working C# for years and in the OR-Mappers I used there, that was no problem at all.
Edit:
I also tried the following version now:
return #Predicate{
    $0.box == 1 || ($0.box == 2 && $0.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus3Days) || ($0.box == 3 && $0.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus7Days) || ($0.box == 4 && $0.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus14Days) || ($0.box == 5 && $0.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus30Days)
}

error again: the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.
return #Predicate{
    $0.box == 1 || ($0.box == 2 && $0.lastStatusChange >= todayMinus3Days)
}

This doesn't throw an exception so 2 expressions seems to be short enough, but how can I add the other expressions? I need them in it :D

I found the answer, very ugly from my perspective of good code, but it works. If someone has a cleaner approach I'm open for it. :)
static func GetCardsToLearnPredicate() -> Predicate<Card> {     
    let todayMinus3Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -3)
    let todayMinus7Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -7)
    let todayMinus14Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -14)
    let todayMinus30Days: Date = Date.now.addDay(day: -30)
           
    let box1 = #Predicate<Card> { $0.box == 1 }
    let box2 = #Predicate<Card> { $0.box == 2 && $0.lastStatusChange <= todayMinus3Days }
    let box3 = #Predicate<Card> { $0.box == 3 && $0.lastStatusChange <= todayMinus7Days }
    let box4 = #Predicate<Card> { $0.box == 4 && $0.lastStatusChange <= todayMinus14Days }
    let box5 = #Predicate<Card> { $0.box == 5 && $0.lastStatusChange <= todayMinus30Days }

    return #Predicate<Card> {
        box1.evaluate($0) || box2.evaluate($0) || box3.evaluate($0) || box4.evaluate($0) || box5.evaluate($0)
    }
}

